# Selenium how do find and click this specific attribute

Tags: selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2aFQ9.jpg)Code 1

button style="margin-left:0px" class="list_header_search_toggle icon-search btn btn-icon table-btn-lg">Search

Code 2

button style="margin-left:0px" class="list_header_search_toggle icon-search btn btn-icon table-btn-lg">

Please help me to find and click this specific element

I tried this but its not working

//WebElement checkSearchGlass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@class,'list_header_search_toggle')"));

```
    //WebElement checkSearchGlass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[starts-with(@class,'list_header_search_toggle')"));
```

Comment: <button style="margin-left:0px" class="list_header_search_toggle icon-search btn btn-icon table-btn-lg"><span class="sr-only">Search</span></button>

Answer (score 0):

I see that your xpath doesn't have closing ] symbol try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[starts-with(@class,'list_header_search_toggle')]"));
```

For a future reference: You may execute xpath in chrome dev tools using $x() command so you would avoid debugging your xpath in webdriver.

Comment: Whole Code
Question1
<button style="margin-left:0px" class="list_header_search_toggle icon-search btn btn-icon table-btn-lg"><span class="sr-only">Search</span></button>

Comment: or
Question 2
When I click it on firebug below codes are highlighted

Comment: <button style="margin-left:0px" class="list_header_search_toggle icon-search btn btn-icon table-btn-lg">

Comment: What kind of exception do you see?

Comment: There are two similar code like that when I search it using on Firebug

Answer (score 0):

Try JavascriptExecutor to click the element,

Refer code,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[starts-with(@class,'list_header_search_toggle')]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```